# How to get statusCode from useError in TypeScript in Nuxt

Tags: typescript, error-handling, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, nuxt3

I use the following code (simplified) to create custom error page in Nuxt project:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
const props = defineProps({
  error: Error,
});

function onClearError() {
  clearError({ redirect: "/" });
}
</script>

<template>
// ...
{{ props.error }}
// ...
</template>
```

The problem is, "error" property passed by Nuxt only contains error message, like "Error: Page not found: /bookmarks/errr".

What I want to do, is to get error code too, e.g. 404, 500, etc.

In the definition of useError() here: https://nuxt.com/docs/api/composables/use-error it is said that it return `statusCode`, but I just can't find how to get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to call the `prop` in your template. You can directly call the `error` object, like this.

```
<h1>{{ error.statusCode }}</h1>
```

To display the Error message

```
<div>{{ error.statusMessage }}</div>
```

Ensure to create an `error.vue` page in your root directory.

`~error.vue`

```js
<script lang="ts" setup>
defineProps({
  error: Object,
});
</script>
<template>
  <div>
    <div>
      <h1>{{ error.statusCode }}</h1>
    </div>
    <div>
      {{ error.statusMessage }}
    </div>
    <div>
      <button @click="clearError({ redirect: '/' })">Back to Home</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

I created an example for you
https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-starter-bqwk4j?file=error.vue

The first link will render a 404 not found page since the `about` page does not exist on the app. And the other one, I manually throw an error to render and error to that page. Hope this will help you.

If you want to know more about error handling, you can find the nuxt example here
https://nuxt.com/docs/examples/app/error-handling

#### Edit: Specified types

Unsure why the types are not specified in the `error` props but if you want, you do it like this

```js
interface IError {
    statusCode: number
    statusMessage: string
    message: string
}

defineProps<{
    error: IError
}>()
```

Or, this

```js
interface IError {
    statusCode: number
    statusMessage: string
    message: string
}

defineProps({
    error: Object as PropType<IError>
})
```

EDIT:

#### ✅ Recommended

```js
<script lang="ts" setup>
defineProps<{
    error: Error
}>()
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works! But it's strange for me that we must use `Object` as type for `error` prop, not `Error`. And `Error` does not contain `statusCode` for some reason...

Comment: Yeah, I noticed it too. In case you still need it, I edited my answer. Try it, it should work like what you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you are so generous! :) I really didn't think that I can create any interface I need and explicitly type-cast `error` for more explicit code! Thanks again for the idea!